# Why is this question locked down?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We had a question asked a few hours ago about the world of Fallout 3: [Fallout - Vault 87](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/291984/108003).

I don't fully understand what happened with it, but it seems to have been [migrated to Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12104/108003) at one point.

This seems like a pretty clear case of asking about "[Plot and characters in games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)". There's an aspect of the game world which doesn't make sense to the asker, from an in-universe perspective, and they want it explained. Seems pretty squarely on-topic.

Can we answer this? If we can't answer it here, for some reason, I'm certain we could answer it at Sci-Fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange. I'd probably answer it myself.

Comment: It was asked on meta initially, and migrated to main by fredley. Since it's seen by the system as a migration reject, community locked it.

Comment: @Unionhawk Ah, okay. Well hopefully that means a mod will take care of it whenever they get to it.

Comment: Actually, it was on the main to begin with. It was suggested to get moved to meta by a user on the main site. It was deleted and posted here, then closed, sent back to main, and then closed there as well.

Comment: @Vemonus What the... well that's odd. Are we in agreement that it's an on-topic question, at least? Not necessarily a great question, as it's based on a misunderstanding, but at least on-topic.

Comment: @DCShannon, I was one of the 5 who VTC'd due to it appearing to be too theoretical. The way it's worded currently makes it seem like a Game Dev intent question about the lore, so I think it should get edited first, but if it is, I see no issue with reopening it.

Comment: @Vemonus I don't see the game design angle at all. Not saying it's not there, but I don't know where. If it gets unlocked I'm sure it could be tweaked. Short answer (from memory, would research to confirm): the nuke didn't hit the vault door, it landed on the surface above the vault.

Comment: I think this part "I understand that the majority, if not all the nukes used in the Great War were relatively low yield in terms of explosion, but that doesn't give the slightest hint/explanation of how a Vault door can withstand a direct hit like that." really seemed like something that wouldn't have been discussed in the game. In my mind, it was extrapolation past the point of being on-topic, but looking back, I think it is on-topic, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

Migration issues aside, I still think it's off topic. It's asking, essentially, why the world in-game doesn't act like you might expect the real world to act. To answer such a question, you'd need to either 1) be an expert in some area of physics outside the realm of expertise that gamers have, to explain why this physical action could happen the way it did, or 2) be the developer of the game, to explain some hidden bit of information not addressed in the canon of the game.

Either way, that's not an appropriate question for a site that has expert gamers to ask expert gaming questions. This isn't a *gaming* question.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the question makes you think that it's about how "you might expect the real world to act". I mean, yeah, the game world physics are related to real world physics, so knowledge in that area might help, but I don't know why you wouldn't just answer the in-universe question in an in-universe way.

Comment: If it was unlocked, we could ask the asker to clarify if they're asking about in or out of universe physics, and edit to clarify.

Comment: For the record, I never like questions of this type. Things that aren't directly addressed by the story, speculative questions about "why" the events played out the way they did, are getting into gray-area territory of answerability and generally make for poor questions, even if they are on topic. I'm not going to vote to keep closed or reopen one way or another; any vote I cast will likely just be a downvote.

Comment: Well that's all fine, and you're certainly entitled to those opinions. It would be nice if we could just get it unlocked so we could ask clarifying questions in comments and potentially cast reopen votes, if enough people think it should be reopened.

Comment: @DCShannon can't we cast reopen votes on the meta one?